# Firebase with angular: creating user was failed

Tags: firebase, angular5

Recently with:

Angular: 5.2

Firebase SDK: 4.13.0

npm: 6.0.0

node: v8.11.1

trying to create a user registration with firebase using this code:

signup.component.html:

```
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSignup(form)" #form="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="form-control" ngModel>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Password">Password</label>
        <input name="Password" id="Password" type="text" class="form-control"   ngModel>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
```

signup.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import {AuthService} from '../auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { } 

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSignup(form: NgForm) {
    const email = form.value.email;
    const password = form.value.password;
    this.authService.signupUser(email, password);
  }

}
```

and in AuthService.service.ts:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService{
token: string;

constructor(private router: Router) {}

  signupUser(email: string, password: string) {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch(
        error => console.log(error) 
      );
  }}
```

but it still throw this error on console once I click on Register button:

```
ERROR 
N {code: "auth/argument-error", message: "createUserWithEmailAndPassword failed: Second argument "password" must be a valid string.", ngDebugContext: DebugContext_, ngErrorLogger: ƒ}
code:
"auth/argument-error"
message:
"createUserWithEmailAndPassword failed: Second argument "password" must be a valid string."
```

So is there a chance of creating a new user with this method using firebase SDK?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SDK is correct, it looks like you've got a typo in your HTML.

`<input name="Password" id="Password" type="text" class="form-control"   ngModel>`

The `id` and `name` are both uppercase property `Password` - but in your `signupUser` function you're attempting the access the lowercase property `password`.

Try update the HTML to `<input name="password" id="password" type="text" class="form-control" ngModel>`

Comment: It worked fine thanks! I forgot to check the spelling ;)